# Wordpress multisite install on ubuntu (nginx) add SSL certificate to checkout only

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, ssl, nginx

I have just moved my wordpress multisite to a digital ocean cloud server running ubuntu (nginx).

One of my page on my primary blog (i.e. the main site) is a checkout page (your-account) and the payment gateway requires an ssl certificate. When you go to http://example.com/your-account it forces https, however, if you were to then return to the homepage, https is still being used. Is ther a way to force http on all pages except for checkout?

Here is my nginx conf file:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
server_name skizzar.com *.skizzar.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/skizzar/www.skizzar.com.chained.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/skizzar/www.skizzar.com.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;

root /usr/share/nginx/skizzar;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
    rewrite files/(.+) /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last;
```

}

```
location /nothingtosee {
    auth_basic "Admin Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
}

location ~ /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
access_log  /var/log/nginx/$host-access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/wpms-error.log;
}
```